# How to uncheck checkbox element after deleting it from append element on onclick event of image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here is My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yv9vypu/2/)I want to uncheck the checkbox when element is delete from another div.Here i am appending checkbox content to another div with delete link.

```
function show() {
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("trainig_by_industry1");
    document.getElementById("selectBox").innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            var da = checkBoxes[i].value;
            document.getElementById("selectBox").innerHTML += '<span class="tagRemove" >' + da + ' <img src="resources/images/Cancel-128.png" id="unc" style="height:20px; width:20px;" onclick="$(this).parent().remove(); check1();"/></span>';
        }
    }
}

function check1() {
    $('#subc1 input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked'); //$(checkBoxes[i]).attr('checked',false); }
```

Comment: when i am click on appended cross image it remove from selectBox div but not unchecked in checkbox. When i call check1() it unchecked all checkbox. How should i unchecked a particular checkbox according to selectbox div element

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: i Have share the fiddle link above. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a `data attribute` to each `checkbox` like 1,2,3.. like this:

```
<label for="one"><input type="checkbox" data-index="1" class="check" name="trainig_by_industry1" onchange="show()"  value="First checkbox" />First checkbox</label>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then in JS:

Add the data-index to its corrosponding  you create.

```
document.getElementById("selectBox").innerHTML+=  '<span class="tagRemove" data-index='+checkBoxes[i].getAttribute('data-index')+' >'+ da+ ' <img src="" alt="X" id="unc" style="height:20px; width:20px;"/></span>';
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then attach a click event to the new `span class tagRemove` instead of writing a `onclick` :

```
$(document).on('click', '.tagRemove' , function(){
  $('#subc1').find('[data-index="'+$(this).data("index")+'"]').prop('checked',false);
  $(this).remove();
})
```

See the ***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yv9vypu/3/)***

Comment: @humble.rumble This is just one way of doing it. Ofcrse there are other more optimized ways. ;)